# xml to json conversion c++

Tags: c++, json, xml, rapidxml, rapidjson

I'm developing a C++ (visual studio 2005) app which converts `xml` to `json` I'm using `rapidxml` and `rapidjson` libraries.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
     <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
     <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
     <genre>Computer</genre>
     <price>44.95</price>
     <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
     <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

**Json** :

```
{
  "catalog": {
           "book": {
              "-id": "bk101",
              "author": "Gambardella, Matthew",
              "title": "XML Developer's Guide",
              "genre": "Computer",
              "price": "44.95",
              "publish_date": "2000-10-01",
              "description": "An in-depth look at creating applications with XML."
           }
   }
}
```

I got this

```
{"catalog":{}}
```

What should I do to make my code parse all entities  in the XML trees.

I think my problem comes from this part of the code:

**C++** :

```
std::string xml2json(const char *xml_str)
{
std::cout<<xml_str;
rapidxml::xml_document<> *xml_doc = new rapidxml::xml_document<>();
xml_doc->parse<0> (const_cast<char *>(xml_str));

rapidjson::Document js_doc;
js_doc.SetObject();
rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = js_doc.GetAllocator();

rapidxml::xml_node<> *xmlnode_chd;

for(xmlnode_chd = xml_doc->first_node()->first_node(); xmlnode_chd; xmlnode_chd = xmlnode_chd->next_sibling())
{
    rapidjson::Value jsvalue_chd;
    jsvalue_chd.SetObject();
    rapidjson::Value jsvalue_name(xmlnode_chd->name(), allocator);
    js_doc.AddMember(jsvalue_name, jsvalue_chd, allocator);
}

delete xml_doc;
rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
buffer.Clear();
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
js_doc.Accept(writer);
return buffer.GetString();
}
```

Comment: Error is on line 57.

Comment: could you be more clear

Comment: @BOUKERIBesmen it is you who needs to be more clear.

Comment: Show us your code instead of just posting the XML and JSON

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? *Can* you read the XML document properly? *Can* you create the output array properly? Does your code enter the loop at all?  What does `js_doc` contain once you exit the loop?

Comment: js_doc contains {"catalog":{}}

Comment: when debbuging xmlnode_chd = xmlnode_chd->next_sibling() contains null !!

Answer (score 0):

You iterate across all the siblings of the root node, but **you never process their children**. You'll need to use an algorithm that traverses every level of the tree. A recursive one would be the conventional choice.